# mule 4 DataWeave2.0 swaping object,key and values from json payload

Tags: json, key-value, dataweave, mule4, array-map

i'm facing an issue while trying to change data from payload and converting it to another api which requires different type of input with same values

input payload

```
{"metadata":
    {"attributes":
        [
        {
            "name":"FromDate",
            "value":"22-09-2021"
        },
        {
            "name":"ToDate",
            "value":"22-02-2022"
        }
        {
            "name":"Purchased",
            "value":"21-02-2021"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

expected output payload

```
{"attributes":
    {
    "FromDate":"22-09-2021",
    "ToDate":"22-02-2022",
    "Purchased":"21-02-2021"
    }
}
```

i have tried the below code to transform the data but unable to acheive the result

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "attributes": payload."metadata"."attributes" map ((item, index) -> {(item."name"):item."value"})
}
```

any suggestions and answers are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could as well do something purely using map.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
attributes: {(payload.metadata.attributes map {
    ($.name): ($.value)
})}
```

Comment: Are you guessing that or did you actually try the script?

Comment: @saiteja0555 the reason it doesn't is because he wrapped it in the `{` and `}`. That collapses the array of objects into a single object. I personally prefer the reduce since it is clear what we're doing and the deconstruct pattern in DWL isn't well documented, but his solution works perfectly.

Comment: To clarify - the reason it doesn't output an array of objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
attributes: 
    payload.metadata.attributes reduce (
        (item,accum={}) -> 
            accum ++ { (item.name): (item.value)}
    )
```

I would suggest going to https://dwlang.fun and using the Tutorial tab in the top right. It goes through common scenarios, and does specifically cover things like `map`, `mapObject` and `reduce`.